# Rails change the Hash by iterator and the value in hash is all the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As the code I wrote, I tried to make arrangement by date

```
@period = Date.new(2019,3,1)..Date.new(2019,3,31)

@deals = Deal.includes(:staff).where(shop_id:1, created_at:@period).group_by{|t| t.staff}
```

In the function `computed_deals` I created I want to make sum of each staff item selling in one day

```
def computed_deals(deals, period ,shop_id)

 #step 1 create empty container and initialize the value
 data = {}
 staff_id_container = {
  total:{item1: 0, item2: 0, item3: 0}
 }

 Staff.where(shop_id: shop_id).select(:id).each do |staff|
  staff_id_container[staff.id] = {item1:0, item2:0, item3:0}
 end

 period.each do |date|
  data[date] = staff_id_container.dup
 end

 #step2 fill it up by true value
 deals.each do |staff, deals_by_staff|
  deals_by_staff.group_by{|t| t.created_at.to_date}.each do |date, selected_deals|
   data[date][staff.id] = {
    item1: select_deals.select{|deal| deal.item == "item1"}.count
    item2: select_deals.select{|deal| deal.item == "item2"}.count
    item3: select_deals.select{|deal| deal.item == "item3"}.count
   }
  end
 end
 #step3 make sum from each staff for each day
 period.map do |date|
    sum_item1 = sum_item2 = sum_item3 = 0
    puts "top"
    puts sum_item1
    deals.each do |staff, deals_by_staff|
      sum_item1 = data[date][staff.id][:item1]+sum_item1
      sum_item2 = data[date][staff.id][:item2]+sum_item2
      sum_item3 = data[date][staff.id][:item3]+sum_item3
    end
    data[date][:total][:item1] = sum_item1.dup
    data[date][:total][:item2] = sum_item2.dup
    data[date][:total][:item3] = sum_item3.dup
    puts "bottom"
    puts sum_item1
  end
end
```

But in the step 3, all of the value of `total` are duplicating from the last day.
I think the problem is that variable was changed when implement each iteration, and the value has been given was changed simultaneously.

```
@data = computed_deals(@period, @deals, 1)
puts @data["2019-03-01".to_date][:total] == @data["2019-03-02".to_date][:total] #true
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: you are setting the same key data[date][:total][:item1] 3 times with the different values in step 3 is it correct?

Comment: @Venom thanks a lot, I have changed it